# MongoDB Schema Design for Time Tracking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose, nosql

I have created a simple time tracking application in which people can TimeIn, TimeOut and mark breaks. The central object to this Tracking is an **Event** generated by **User**. This combined with **UserStatus** makes sure the state management is correct. Here are the schemas minus *updatedAt* *createdAt* fields:

```
{
  userId: { type   : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  localTime:  {type: Date},
  userEmail: { type: String, required: true },
  type: { type   : String, required: true },
  ip: { type   : String, required: false }
}
```

Now I am trying to create an aggregation of a days event. The fields in my mind are totalWorkTime, totalBreakTime (in seconds), noOfBreaks but the case I am trying to tackle is when users forget to timeout. Please consider:

- Users are in far US as well as in Manilla.
- Users dont have any time period assigned to them.
- So Perhaps they can work from 11PM to 3AM by their local time.
- How the differentiate the above situation from missing timeout and it fits well with local timezones.
- Is storing local time smart? Opposed to storing UTCs.

Primary thinking was to timein and timeout at 11:59PM and 12:00AM the next day. But it dosent fit well. Any help with Schema or perhaps suggested schema shall be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store the times in UTC and their timezone offset.

```
const now = new Date();
console.log( now.getTime() );
console.log( now.getTimezoneOffset() );
```